# How do I play quarter tones in "Violin" style?

Tags: sound

I am trying to use the SoundNote command with "Violin" as my instrument but I cannot see how I can play quarter tones and smaller denominations ("cents").

Comment: Please clarify the question: "quarter note" typically refers to the duration of the note. Do you mean "quarter tone", which refers to the pitch?

Comment: yes, sorry, quarter tone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the answer is you cannot play MIDI notes in *Mathematica* at a cent pitch granularity. Try this:

```
music1 = Sound[SoundNote["C", 1.25, "Violin"]]
music2 = Sound[SoundNote["CSharp", 1.25, "Violin"]]
Export["music1.mid", music1]
Export["music2.mid", music2]
```

Diff the files:
[image: midi files diff bytes]

There's no byte in between 3C and 3D and these notes were interpreted to be a semitone apart. So we know at least we probably cannot export a quarter tone from *Mathematica* - and I guess it cannot play these notes in the notebook either.

I was thinking maybe I could use the .mid file format spec to edit the .mid files to apply a Pitch Wheel Change message and load it back in, but we're drifting further away from *Mathematica* at this point. 
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/Standard-MIDI-file-format-updated.pdf

**However**, if you just want to hear the note you can `AudioPitchShift` it.
This adds some distortion. If you load the `Music` package you can get the ratio you need to pitch shift a standard 440Hz $A^\natural$ to get a quarter note.

```
<< Music`
(*https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Music/tutorial/Music.html*)
quartertoneRatio = #[[2]]/#[[1]] &@CentsToHertz[QuarterTone];
semitoneRatio = #[[3]]/#[[1]] &@CentsToHertz[QuarterTone];
music1 = Sound@SoundNote["A", 1.25, "Violin"]
quartertoneHigherAsPitchShift = AudioPitchShift[music1, quartertoneRatio]
semitoneHigher = Sound@SoundNote["ASharp", 1.25, "Violin"]
(* Verify the below Audio sounds the same as the semitoneHigher note *)
semitoneHigherAsPitchShift = AudioPitchShift[music1, semitoneRatio]
```